# String separation and combining

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a challenge that I am trying to solve and cannot seem to come up with a solid solution.

I have 3 records like this:

```
"a,b,c,d,e","1,2,3,4,5","record 1"
"f,g,h,i","11,12,15,16","record 2"
"x,y,z","19,20,21","record 3"
```

Looking to create this output

```
"a,1"
"b,2"
"c,3"
"d,4"
"e,5"
...
...
"y,20"
"z,21"
```

How would I go about this using java-script or

I have have worked out how to separate each string but collecting both substrings and looping through seems to be a challenge.

Comment: are these records in JSON format ? they do not seem to be strings... what's the exact structure for each record?

Comment: @GuyL - That's definitely not JSON.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? It is expected that you at least try to find a solution yourself and if you have issues, then ask questions about the specific issues.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its doesn't seem so in the question,but what datatype should it be in, this is a JS question...

Comment: no need for a substring, `.split()` and `.join()` (and some loops) should be all you need

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. (An MCVE would, amongst other things, make it clear exactly what your input is, and how you've attempted to separate the strings, etc.) People will be glad to help.

Comment: it's not clear what your input is. Is one line a string, or 3 strings in an array?

Comment: Jeff its 3 strings in an array. Format was a CSV file that was extracted from an old DB.

Answer (score 1):

This can get a little bit Tricky if you dont have a constant format.

In this example i have two strings and each sub-string is separated by ",".

Also both strings should be the same length.

I return the result as an array here. You can append it to a existing string instead.

```js
s1 = "1,2,3,4,5";
s2 = "a,b,c,d,e";
s3 = [];
for(i=0; s1.length>i;i++){
  if(s1[i] != ","){
    s3.push(s1[i]+","+s2[i]);
  }
}
console.log(s3);
```

Since im not sure if i did understand the Question correctly...
If you dont understand something or the answer is not what you excepted, let me know in the comments and i will try to adapt to it.